# How to put CSS on background image

Tags: html, css

So, I have one div

```html
<div id="particles-js" >
```

and in css I have

```css
#particles-js{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #b61924;
  background-image: url("../js/image.jpg");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

but I also need to put some black overlay effects on image before it sets background.
How to do that?

image style..

```css
.image {
  width:100%;
  vertical-align:top;
  content:'\A';
  position:absolute;
   height:100%;
  top:0; left:0;
  background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
  opacity:0.5;
  transition: all 0.5s;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}
```

Comment: `.image` what is `.image` ? Also your `.image` uses `content: '\A';` which is only valid for `:before` and `:after` pseudo elements. So... you meant to use actually: `#particles-js:after {`  - instead of that `.image {` ?

Comment: I forgot to delete content:'\A';.  and .image was style for image. Anyway, @Goman60 answer works like a charm

Comment: Oh, well then. Nice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might try this. It will add a black overlay to the image. You can change the rgb to rgba to make it more transparent.

```
background:linear-gradient(0deg, rgb(0, 0, 0), rgb(0, 0, 0)), url("../js/image.jpg");
```